# Chained AJAX call access to the response

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have two chained AJAX call.

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/reservation/order',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
            "check_in": checkIn,
            "check_out": checkOut,
            "type_payment": "xxxx",
            "total_nights": totalNights,
            "total_guests": totalGuests,
            "total_rooms": +totalRooms,
            "total_amount": +totalAmount,
            "booking_data": bookingData,
            "first_name": firstName,
            "last_name": lastName,
            "company_name": companyName,
            "address": address,
            "city": townCity,
            "country": country,
            "email": email,
            "phone": phone,
            "guest_remark": guestRemark,
            "room_rates": formattedRoomRate
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(response){
        orderId = response
        proceedToPayment(orderId, "xxxx")
    })
```

Whereas proceed payment is second AJAX

```
function proceedToPayment(orderId, paymentType){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/reservation/payment',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
            "payment_type": paymentType,
            "order_id": orderId,
            "cust_ip": custIP,
            "cust_name": firstName,
            "cust_email": email,
            "cust_phone": phone
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            console.log("test")
            console.log(response)
            window.location.href(response);                
        }
    })
}
```

The network tab in inspect element tells me that i have successfully fire the ajax in sequential order. I can see the value returned by server is the correct value.
However, i cannot access the response returned by second AJAX call.
Why is that? Or is there any way to return redirect on server instead?
Which one is better?

Comment: You should be able to see both ajax functions execute in the element network tab. Because of the redirect the network tab probably will be empty again because you're opening a new page. You can't redirect on server with an ajax request.

Comment: Just maybe your inability to access response in the success handler of the second ajax call is because your HTTP POST request wasn't successful. Add an error handler to check this.

Comment: Can you clarify *"i cannot access the response returned by second AJAX call"* please?  How are you trying to "access" it (other than the code provided).  Does it work if you remove the `window.location.href=` line?  Are you trying to access it outside the `success:` callback?  Are you sure the 2nd call is hitting the success?  (there's no `error:` callback)

Comment: Definitely remove `window.location.href(response);` if you want to remain on the same window. That way, you can view the Network tab and see what your second response is.

Comment: @TonyM: i cannot go to the next window , which is what i want to achieve..
Network tab, yes, i get the desired second response

Comment: @OluwafemiSule: But i can see the response on the network tab,
i still dont know why i cannot access the success callback

Comment: @Brian Ruchiadi add an error handler to see what's going on.